# Pivoting and Distributing values based on Duration

Tags: r

I have a small dataset `weekly_data` of projects were working on, and anticipated time to be spent and duration in weeks for each of the two milestones, labeled CD and CA

```
# A tibble: 17 x 5
   dsk_proj_number hrs_per_week_cd cd_dur_weeks hrs_per_week_ca ca_dur_weeks
   <fct>                     <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 17061                      0               0            2.43           28
 2 18009                      0               0            1.83           12
 3 18029                      0               0            2.83           24
 4 19029                      1.5            16            2.43           28
 5 19050                      0               0            2.8            20
 6 20012                      0               0            3.4            20
 7 21016                      3               8            2.43           28
 8 21022                      0               0            4.25           16
 9 21050                      0               0            3.4            20
10 21061a                    17.5            24           15.8            52
11 21061b                     1.5             4            7.5             8
12 21061c                     7.67           12            5              12
13 21061d                     0               0            0               0
14 21061e                     8               1            3               1
15 21094                      0               0            3               8
16 22027                      0               0            0.75            8
17 22068                      2.92           12            2.38            8
```

I want to get this into a format wheree, based on the `cd_dur_weeks` and `ca_dur_weeks` durations indicated, I have the estiamted number of hours by weeks, for all the weeks, like this:

```
> sched %>% head(15)
# A tibble: 15 x 17
   `18009` `22068` `17061` `21050` `19029` `21016` `21022` `19050` `18029` `22027` `20012` `21094` `21061a` `21061b` `21061c` `21061d` `21061e`
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      1.5     7.67        0        8
 2    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      1.5     7.67        0        3
 3    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      1.5     7.67        0        0
 4    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      1.5     7.67        0        0
 5    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
 6    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
 7    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
 8    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    3       4.25     2.8    2.83    0.75     3.4       3     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
 9    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
10    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
11    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
12    1.83    2.92    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      7.5     7.67        0        0
13    0       2.38    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      0       5           0        0
14    0       2.38    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      0       5           0        0
15    0       2.38    2.43     3.4     1.5    2.43    4.25     2.8    2.83    0        3.4       0     17.5      0       5           0        0
```

I was able to use `pivot_wider()` to make the project numbers the variable names, and each row an individual week, but was forced to use `for()`'s and `if()`'s. Seems like there should be an easier way to get this done.

Here's the code I used:

```
sched <- data.frame(dsk_proj_number = rezvan$dsk_proj_number)
sched$weeks <- NA
sched <- sched %>% pivot_wider(names_from = dsk_proj_number, values_from = weeks)


for(proj_num in weekly_data$dsk_proj_number){
  duration_cd = weekly_data[which(weekly_data$dsk_proj_number == proj_num), "cd_dur_weeks"] %>% as.numeric
  duration_ca = weekly_data[which(weekly_data$dsk_proj_number == proj_num), "ca_dur_weeks"] %>% as.numeric
  
  if(duration_cd > 0) {
    sched[1:duration_cd, proj_num] = weekly_data[which(weekly_data$dsk_proj_number == proj_num), "hrs_per_week_cd"]
  }
  
  if(duration_ca > 0) {
    sched[duration_cd + 1:duration_ca, proj_num] = weekly_data[which(weekly_data$dsk_proj_number == proj_num), "hrs_per_week_ca"]
  }
  
  
}



sched <- sched %>% mutate_all(coalesce, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep()` to repeat elements a certain number of times, and then use `c()` to concatenate them into a long sequence.  I use `rowwise` from `dplyr` to conveniently do this row-by-row.

Then you can `unnest` the lists of vectors.

```
library(tidyverse)
sched <- weekly_data %>% 
    mutate(max_weeks = max(cd_dur_weeks + ca_dur_weeks)) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(week = list(c(rep(hrs_per_week_cd, cd_dur_weeks), rep(hrs_per_week_ca, ca_dur_weeks), rep(0, max_weeks-cd_dur_weeks-ca_dur_weeks)))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(dsk_proj_number, week) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = "dsk_proj_number", values_from = week) %>% 
    unnest(everything())
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Exactly what I was trying for, but didn't think of using the list!

Answer (score 0):

```r
df %>% 
    select(1:3) %>% 
    slice(rep(1:nrow(.), cd_dur_weeks)) %>% 
    select(-3) %>%
    mutate(milestone = 1) %>%
    rename(hrs_per_week = hrs_per_week_cd) -> df1

df %>% 
    select(c(1,4,5)) %>% 
    slice(rep(1:nrow(.), ca_dur_weeks)) %>% 
    select(-3) %>%
    mutate(milestone = 2) %>%
    rename(hrs_per_week = hrs_per_week_ca) -> df2

rbind(df1, df2) %>%
    arrange(dsk_proj_number, milestone) %>%
    group_by(dsk_proj_number) %>%
    mutate(week = seq_along(dsk_proj_number)) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols=week, names_from=dsk_proj_number, values_from=hrs_per_week) %>%
    replace(is.na(.), 0)
```